# Shared Prefereces saved names not showing after restarting the App

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am creating an app that saves that saves user's previous names. I am using Shared Preferences so when the user kills the app and reopens it the names will still show in the saved Activity. The app currently displays the saved names, but once it's closed and the life cycle is killed, and then restarted the names aren't retrieved.

Code to save the names:

```
protected void addToSaved(String s){

    GlobalList.pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // 0 - for private mode
    SharedPreferences.Editor  editor = GlobalList.pref.edit();

    if(GlobalList.tagsActive.size() < 6){


        GlobalList.tagsActive.addFirst(GlobalList.tagsAvail.removeFirst());
        editor.putString(GlobalList.tagsActive.getFirst(), s);




    }else{
       editor.remove(GlobalList.tagsActive.removeLast());
       GlobalList.tagsAvail.add(GlobalList.tagsActive.removeLast());


        //adding shared pref
        GlobalList.tagsActive.addFirst(GlobalList.tagsAvail.removeFirst());
        editor.putString(GlobalList.tagsActive.getFirst(), s); // Storing string value
    }

    //GlobalList.editor.commit(); // commit changes into sharedpreferences file.

    editor.commit();
```

Code to retrieve and display the names:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_names);



        for (int i = 0; i < GlobalList.tagsActive.size(); i++) {

            //setting martian name to screen
           // getting String

            nameTexts[i] = (TextView) findViewById(textId[i]);
            //set conditon here so no null pointer
            GlobalList.pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // 0 - for private mode
            String s =GlobalList.pref.getString(GlobalList.tagsActive.get(i), "");
            nameTexts[i].setText(s);


        }


    }
}
```

Code for global list so can be edited across classes:

```
public class GlobalList {


   static LinkedList<String> tagsAvail = new LinkedList<String>();
   static LinkedList<String> tagsActive = new LinkedList<String>();
   static SharedPreferences pref;
    static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because when the app starts up on onCreate, the length of  GlobalList.tagsActive.size() is zero, so the code inside the FOR loop does not execute.

Change your FOR loop for this:

```
while (true) {
   //setting martian name to screen
   // getting String

   //set conditon here so no null pointer
   GlobalList.pref =      getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // 0 - for private mode
   String s =GlobalList.pref.getString(GlobalList.tagsActive.get(i), "");

   if (s.equals("")){
      break; //exits while loop if no more items are found in SharedPref
   else{
      nameTexts[i] = (TextView) findViewById(textId[i]); 
      nameTexts[i].setText(s);
   }
}
```

Comment: How would I go about unwrapping SharedPreferences?

Comment: I added some changes to the code, it should work more or less like that @user3397546